# Where does TeamCity's build agent look for the .NET Core SDK / Mono?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono, teamcity

I'm having trouble configuring my build agents for TeamCity. It appears that the agent (I'm running with the image provided by Jetbrains) doesn't see the .NET Core installation on my host machine, nor does it see mono. I'm assuming that something is getting lost in translation as I'm trying to configure this on openSUSE- How can I explicitly tell the runner where .NET Core is located? The locations of both .NET Core and Mono are specified in `$PATH` and `$DOTNET_HOME` is also configured, but I still see these messages upon starting the agent:

```
[2023-11-13 20:37:11,265]   INFO - nstall.PackagesInstallerRunner - NuGet requires .NET Framework (x86) 4.0 and higher or Mono 3.2 and higher to be installed.
[2023-11-13 20:37:11,275]   INFO - t.agent.runner.pack.PackRunner - NuGet requires .NET Framework (x86) 4.0 and higher or Mono 3.2 and higher to be installed.
[2023-11-13 20:37:11,275]   INFO - .publish.PackagesPublishRunner - NuGet requires .NET Framework (x86) 4.0 and higher or Mono 3.2 and higher to be installed.
```

How do I need to adjust my configuration? Do I need to install these dependencies directly into the container somehow?

From the docs:

> Supported Build Runners
>
> TeamCity supports running .NET builds using
> NAnt and MSBuild runners under Mono framework as well as under .NET
> Frameworks. (MSBuild as xbuild in Mono).
> NuGet runners support Linux and macOS when Mono is installed on the agent. Note that only NuGet CLI 3.2+ on Mono 4.4.2+ is supported.
> Tests reporting tasks are also supported under Mono.

Surely here 'agent' refers to the host machine, and not the container itself?